# Can I insert into a temp table the result of a stored procedure plus another value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a temp table that needs the values of a Stored procedure. So the SP inserts 3 columns into the temp table, then I want to add a datetime to every row without modifying the SP.

Since I call the SP 3 times, each time with a different datetime, I can't just update the whole temp table.

Any Suggestions?

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(150),
    Address VARCHAR(25),
    Date DATETIME
)

WHILE (@count>=@daysBack)
BEGIN
    SET @date=DATEADD(dd, @count, GETDATE())
    INSERT INTO @temp (Name,Address)
        EXEC[dbo].StoredProc@date

--I Want to check for Null and insert the date there
    Update @temp SET Date=@date WHERE Date='' 

    SET @count=@count-1
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you are doing this now?

Comment: Please add some sample data: how do you call the SP and what to you want to see.

Comment: @Mitchel Sellers: second-to-second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create the temp table and in the added date column that does not have representation from your sproc put a default value constraint of getdate() or whatever date formula you need. In the insert statement specify the columns explicitly and omit the date column and it should work. As the rows are added the default value constraint will kick in and fill that column for you.

example:

```
create table #tmp (c1 int, c2 int, dt datetime default(getdate()) )

insert into #tmp
(c1, c2)
exec mysproc
```

Comment: Thanks.... I modified it just a little. I put in the default date... then I updated the default date with the one I wanted to insert in every iteration of the loop.